# How to rewrite both GET and POST to the same endpoint with different response bodies?

Tags: charles-proxy

I need to rewrite with [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), with both GET and POST to the same endpoint expecting different response bodies, i.e.:

`GET` to `endpoint` should return `body1`

while

`POST` to `endpoint` should return `body2`

What I see in Charles' rewrite setting is that there is no differentiation between http method so Charles can't know which one I'm referring to.

My (kinda hack-workaround) solution would be to make my application to use endpoint1 for GET and endpoint2 for POST. Charles' setting would be then:

`GET` to `endpoint1` should return `body1`

`POST` to `endpoint2` should return `body2`

In this way I'm able to have 2 separate rules. But I think this solution is not elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, Charles does not have any capability to distinguish from different HTTP methods, so the best you can do is probably using different endpoints, which, I agree with you, is not very elegant.
Have you tried using some special header? May be you can avoid creating 2 different endpoints...

Let us know if you can!

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite on a POST/GET as a rule but you can set a breakpoint on POST/GET. I agree it's not ideal but what can you do.